# Button doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, onclick

I have

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" onclick="submit()" >foobar</button>
```

When I click the button in firefox, the value is transferred (is foo) and I can read the value like the following:

```
dim mode                : mode                = lcase(request("foo"))
```

But the value is empty when I perform the same action in Chrome.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I don't see the link between your variable `mode` and your button called `foo`?

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake. i edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Firefox :)

Answer (score 4):

Different browsers have different *default* submit behaviors for buttons.  If you want a button to submit the form (and thus post its name and value pair), you'll have to use:

```
<button type="submit" name="foo" value="bar" >foobar</button>
```

The *type* attribute for `button` can be *submit*, *button*, or *reset* and unless this is explicitly specified, will vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Hi, thank you for feedback. I have changed it, but it still doesnt send val name pair.

Comment: Just tried it in IE, Chrome and Firefox and it works, so must be something else to do with your HTML.  What does your FORM tag look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have a quote missing. It should look like this:

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" onclick="submit()" >foobar</button>
```

In addition, submit() is a method on a form, so you must make sure your button is within `<form></form>` tags.

From the [W3C specification](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> **Important**: If you use the  element in an HTML form, different
>   browsers may submit different values. Internet Explorer, prior version
>   9, will submit the text between the `<button>` and `</button>` tags, while
>   other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the
>   `<input>` element to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: sorry, was only typo. i just want to submit form (this work, only the value is empty).the button is in form-tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your attributes:

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" onclick="submit()" >foobar</button>
```

Also "submit" is a reserved word in JavaScript. If you have a function called "submit" it may not work.

List of reserved words: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: sorry, was only typo. i just want to submit form (this work, only the value is empty).

Comment: submit() requires you specify a form reference: document.form1.submit()

Answer (score 0):

If you will it makes easier for google or other to find your form. Give the button an title and alt:

```
 <button name="foo" title="submit" alt="submit for contact" valeu="" onclick="submit()" >foobar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, old versions of IE (maybe even 8) treat only the good old `<input type="submit" />` as "real" submit button that is part of the form thus sending its value. So `<button>` in such browsers won't send its value.

Change the HTML to this and it should work for all browsers:

```
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="foobar" onclick="this.value = 'bar';" />
```

As the value sent is the value seen, I had to use JavaScript trick to change the value upon click - as far as I know, can't do that without using client side script.